# Javascript Classes, Inheritance

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

i need some help with the following lines of code:

```
class Race{
        constructor(_raceName){
            this.raceName = _raceName;
        }
    }

class Animal extends Race{
        constructor(_raceName, _animal) {
            super(_raceName, _animal);
            this.animal = _animal;
        
        }
    }

class Pet extends Animal{
        constructor(_petName, _Birthday, _animal){
            super(_animal)
            this.petName = _petName;
            this.Birthday = _Birthday;
        }
    
    }

var Pet1 = new Pet("Pluto", "2000/10/01", "Mamals")
console.log(Pet1)
```

When i run it in the terminal i get the following:
Pet {
raceName: 'Mamals',
animal: undefined,
petName: 'Pluto',
Birthday: '2000/

why is my Animal undefined? i would like to have the string "dog" in there

Comment: obvious issue: Race constructor takes one argument ... but Animal calls it with two ... Animal constructor takes two arguments, but Pet calls it with one

Comment: second issue, you want Pet1 to be a `dog` - yet the string `dog` doesn't exist in your code? Javascript doesn't know that `Pluto` is a famous name for a dog

Comment: I am not quite sure i understand, how would you do it?

Comment: I would call the `super` with the correct number of arguments in the correct order - as for `dog` ... well, you'd also need to pass that string to something somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Animal` class expects 2 arguments so if you only send one it will make the second one `undefined`. You can put a default value that goes if no value is fed for it to be not `undefined`.

```js
class Race{
        constructor(_raceName){
            this.raceName = _raceName;
        }
    }

class Animal extends Race{
        constructor(_raceName, _animal="dog") {
            super(_raceName, _animal);
            this.animal = _animal;
        
        }
    }

class Pet extends Animal{
        constructor(_petName, _Birthday, _animal){
            super(_animal)
            this.petName = _petName;
            this.Birthday = _Birthday;
        }
    
    }

var Pet1 = new Pet("Pluto", "2000/10/01", "Mamals")
console.log(Pet1)
```

AND, you will have to change your class Pet as below for it to be proper. By default, it will take `"dog"`, you can input your animal class depending upon your implementation.

```js
class Race{
        constructor(_raceName){
            this.raceName = _raceName;
        }
    }

class Animal extends Race{
        constructor(_raceName, _animal="dog") {
            super(_raceName, _animal);
            this.animal = _animal;
        
        }
    }

class Pet extends Animal{
        constructor(_petName,_animalClass, _Birthday, _animal){
            super(_animal,_animalClass)
            this.petName = _petName;
            this.Birthday = _Birthday;
        }
    
    }

var Pet1 = new Pet("Pluto","cat", "2000/10/01", "Mamals")
console.log(Pet1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to add an additional class that would define that the instance is a dog.

```js
class Race{
        constructor(_raceName){
            this.raceName = _raceName;
        }
    }

class Animal extends Race{
        constructor(race, _animal) {
            super(race);
            this.animal = _animal;
        }
    }

class Pet extends Animal{
        constructor(_petName, _Birthday, race, _animal){
            super(race, _animal);
            this.petName = _petName;
            this.Birthday = _Birthday;
        }
    }
    
class Dog extends Pet {
  constructor(...params) {
    super(...params, "dog");
  }
}

var Pet1 = new Dog("Pluto", "2000/10/01", "Mamals")
console.log(Pet1)
```